# SQL Server : workers shift excluding break times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just write this function in SQL Server. It calculate working minutes of worker excluding break times.

```
ALTER FUNCTION getMinutesWork
    ( @startT dateTime,
      @endT dateTime)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int = DATEDIFF(mi, @startT, @endT)  --time difference including break times
    SET @startT = CAST(@startT AS TIME)
    SET @endT = CAST(@endT AS TIME)

    -- work schedule  
    DECLARE @t1 datetime = CAST('08:00:00' AS TIME),  --work
            @t2 datetime = CAST('10:00:00' AS TIME),  --break                   
            @t3 datetime = CAST('10:15:00' AS TIME),  --w
            @t4 datetime = CAST('12:40:00' AS TIME),  --b
            @t5 datetime = CAST('13:25:00' AS TIME),  --w
            @t6 datetime = CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME),  --b 
            @t7 datetime = CAST('16:45:00' AS TIME),  --w
            @t8 datetime = CAST('18:15:00' AS TIME);  --b

    --excluding break times
    IF ((@startT <= @t2 AND @endT >@t2) AND (@startT < @t3 AND @endT >= @t3))
       SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t2, @t3) 

    IF ((@startT <= @t4 AND @endT >@t4) AND (@startT < @t5 AND @endT >= @t5))
       SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t4, @t5)

    IF ((@startT <= @t6 AND @endT >@t6) AND (@startT < @t7 AND @endT >= @t7))
       SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t6, @t7)

    IF ((@startT > @t8) AND (@endT > @t1))
       SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t1, @startT)

    --excluding break times if worker starts on break time
    SET @result = (CASE 
                     WHEN (@startT < @t1) 
                       THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @startT, @t1)
                     WHEN (@startT > @t2 AND @startT < @t3) 
                       THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @startT, @t3)
                     WHEN (@startT > @t4 AND @startT < @t5) 
                       THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @startT, @t5)
                     WHEN (@startT > @t6 AND @startT < @t7) 
                       THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @startT, @t7)
                     WHEN (@startT > @t8) AND (@endT < @t1)
                       THEN 0
                     ELSE @result
                 END)

----------'2004-10-19 20:00:00','2004-10-18 10:00:00'------------
    --excluding break times if worker finish his work on break time
    SET @result = (
CASE 
    WHEN (@endT < @t1) 
        THEN 0
    WHEN (@endT >= @t2 AND @endT < @t3) 
        THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t2,@endT)
    WHEN (@endT >= @t4 AND @endT < @t5) 
        THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t4,@endT)
    WHEN (@endT >= @t6 AND @endT < @t7) 
        THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t6,@endT)
    WHEN (@endT > @t8)
        THEN @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t8,@endT)
    ELSE @result
END )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF @result <0
    SET @result = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RETURN @result
End
```

It works fine when worker comes and goes in same day. But when worker come like 11pm and works until tomorrow 11am it doesn't exclude break times. Any idea please? Sorry for long post btw.

Edit: I found the problem but can't solve it. If there is a overday work like `@startT = '20:00:00'` and `@endT = '10:20:00'`, this part won't work:

```
IF ((@startT <= @t2 AND @endT >@t2) AND (@startT < @t3 AND @endT >= @t3))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t2,@t3) 
IF ((@startT <= @t4 AND @endT >@t4) AND (@startT < @t5 AND @endT >= @t5))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t4,@t5)
IF ((@startT <= @t6 AND @endT >@t6) AND (@startT < @t7 AND @endT >= @t7))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t6,@t7)
```

How can I solve that part?

Comment: You will have no problem if you have date part as well

Comment: All staff have exactly the same break times and there are no breaks between 18:15 and 08:00 for night workers?

Comment: There is no night workes. But normal worker may work 20:00 to 10:00. if that so function should return 2hours and it does. But if worker work 20:00 to 11:00 it doesnt exclude 10:00-10:15 break, that is the problem

Comment: If the shift was `18:00` to `10:30` should the result be `2hrs 30mins`?   (18:00->18:15 + 08:00->10:00 + 10:15->10:30).

Comment: Yes! That is really what Im trying to do

Comment: Do you ever have to cope with shifts longer than 24 hours?

Comment: `SELECT dbo.getMinutesWork('2004-10-18 08:00:00','2004-10-19 08:35:00') AS WorkTime` with this input its gives me 1475 which is included `18:15` to `08:00` but no break times

Comment: But do they ever happen?  Can you state "this doesn't work for shifts longer than 24 hours", or do you *need* to make it work for any length of shift?  Even one 365 days long?

Comment: I dont even know why I have to write like this. Im doing intern and my boss want it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check if this works?
I think this resolves the logical issue.

```html
DECLARE @startT DATETIME = Cast('19:00:00' AS TIME), 
        @endT   DATETIME = Cast('11:00:00' AS TIME); 
DECLARE @result INT = Datediff(mi, @startT, @endT); 
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME = Cast('08:00:00' AS TIME),--work 
        @t2 DATETIME = Cast('10:00:00' AS TIME),--break                    
        @t3 DATETIME = Cast('10:15:00' AS TIME),--w 
        @t4 DATETIME = Cast('12:40:00' AS TIME),--b 
        @t5 DATETIME = Cast('13:25:00' AS TIME),--w 
        @t6 DATETIME = Cast('16:30:00' AS TIME),--b  
        @t7 DATETIME = Cast('16:45:00' AS TIME),--w 
        @t8 DATETIME = Cast('18:15:00' AS TIME); --b 

IF Datediff(mi, @startT, Cast('18:00:00' AS TIME)) < 0 
--I have assumed the employee cannot come before six for the night shift
  BEGIN 
      SET @result = @result + 1440; 
      IF (( @endT >= @t3 )) 
        SET @result = @result - Datediff(mi, @t2, @t3) 
      IF (( @endT >= @t5 )) 
        SET @result = @result - Datediff(mi, @t4, @t5) 
      IF (( @endT >= @t7 )) 
        SET @result = @result - Datediff(mi, @t6, @t7) 
  END 
ELSE 
   BEGIN
  IF ((@startT <= @t2 AND @endT >@t2) AND (@startT < @t3 AND @endT >= @t3))
     SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t2, @t3) 
  IF ((@startT <= @t4 AND @endT >@t4) AND (@startT < @t5 AND @endT >= @t5))
     SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t4, @t5)
  IF ((@startT <= @t6 AND @endT >@t6) AND (@startT < @t7 AND @endT >= @t7))
     SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi, @t6, @t7)
 END
SELECT @result 
--SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST((@result / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
--RIGHT('0' + CAST(@result % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Comment: thank you but i tried something else and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited the if statement part and it worked:

```
--total work time if worker stay overnight including break times
IF ((@startT <= @t8) AND (@endT < @startT))
BEGIN
    SET @result = DATEDIFF(mi,@startT,'23:59:59') + DATEDIFF(mi,'00:00:01',@endT) +1
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t8,'23:59:59') - DATEDIFF(mi,'00:00:01',@t1)-1     
END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --excluding break times

IF (((@startT > @t8) AND (@endT > @t1)))        
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@startT,'23:59:59') - DATEDIFF(mi,'00:00:01',@t1)-1     
IF ((@startT <= @t2 AND @endT >= @t3)) OR ((@startT > @t8) AND (@endT >= @t3))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t2,@t3) 
IF ((@startT <= @t4 AND @endT >= @t5)) OR ((@startT > @t8) AND (@endT >= @t5))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t4,@t5)
IF ((@startT <= @t6 AND @endT >= @t7)) OR ((@startT > @t8) AND (@endT >= @t7))
    SET @result = @result - DATEDIFF(mi,@t6,@t7)
```